# Rich Internet Application (RIA) for Oracle Database Application

Tags: css, silverlight, oracle, html, ria

Our Oracle application is written in Oracle Forms.  However, there is a requirement for it to be a Rich Internet Application (RIA).  I.e. no deployment, accessed via web, looks and navigates (tabbing etc) as closely to a desktop GUI application as possible.

Apex has been discarded as not good enough and will not produce a sufficiently good user experience and does not look good compared to other technologies.

Silverlight is being suggested as the best way forward, but I would like to know what else is out there.

I have had suggestions that the way forward is to use HTML5/CSS, but we need a good framework for managing records.  I do not wish to be reinventing the wheel.  I understand that Silverlight for Business Applications takes care of some of those requirements.

Also, the idea is to create web services in Oracle and have a Silverlight front-end.  Is this possible / the right way of doing things?

Any pointers in the right direction or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Oracle Application Development Framework? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/adf11g-data-sheet-1-133847.pdf

Answer (score 4):

> Apex has been discarded as not good
>   enough and will not produce a
>   sufficiently good user experience and
>   does not look good compared to other
>   technologies.

Oracle Apex has all the features that you are looking for. You can customize it using CSS, users can access it using web and since your current application is in Oracle Forms, you can reuse a lot of your code written in Oracle procedures/packages/triggers. Also, the learning curve for your Oracle Developers would be very smooth.

I'd suggest you to try and create a small module for your future project and see how effective it is in terms of both Development time and the rich UI.

Comment: +1 There is absolutely no web-based look that you cannot replicate using Apex with CSS, so unless the criteria is "must not look like any web application" it surely does look good enough!

Comment: Thanks for that.  Do you have any sample screenshots.  If I Google Oracle Apex screenshots, the screens there are viewed as poor by our company consultants.  The problem is that a lot of the applications in sales demo look very flashy (literally).  Whether they are functionally good and whether a data entry user finds it as good is another matter, but they look good and better than any Apex screen I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about it, but you might want to look at [FormSpider](http://theformspider.com/).

And of course there is [Oracle ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html).

Like Rajesh, I bridle at the suggestion that Apex is "not good enough", having been heavily involved in a [very successful Apex project](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2010/08/fame-at-last-for-my-biggest-apex.html) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the FormSpider link. Looks okay.  I need to look at Oracle ADF also.  I appreciate where you're coming from, but the UI is very important to our company.  Functionally, everything is already very rich using Oracle Forms, but no-one will say that Oracle Forms will win any awards in a sales demo.  Apex is touch and go at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view,there is no direct dependence between your future RIA's and the RDBMS you are using now. In other words,features and advantages of Silverlight\Entity Framework are almost equal for different data sources (e.g SQL Server,Oracle and etc).

> Also, the idea is to create web
>   services in Oracle and have a
>   Silverlight front-end. Is this
>   possible / the right way of doing
>   things?

Using a middle tier (WCF or WCF RIA Services) as a data access layer will be more preferable than creating web-services in Oracle.

This tutorial can be usefull for you to get some general view of the Silverlight and WCF Ria Services.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx